# Quelles seraient d’autres façons de dire « faire faux bond à des convives » de manière que des non francophones comprennent le sens de la phrase?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes, reformulation

Quelles seraient d’autres façons de dire « faire faux bond à des convives » de manière que des non francophones comprennent le sens de la phrase.

Par exemple :

Au dernier moment, j’ai fait faux bond à mes convives car mon véhicule a eu des ennuis mécaniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Au dernier moment j’ai *été forcé de priver* mes convives *de ma présence*  car mon véhicule a eu des ennuis mécaniques.

Comment: Et les convives de répondre : "Ça va les chevilles ?"

Answer (score 1):

Manquer à son devoir (d'hôte, en l'occurrence), se désengager, être retenu par la plus sournoise des contraintes, poser un lapin, manquer un rendez-vous...

Answer (score 0):

- Au dernier moment, *j'ai posé un lapin* à mes convives car ma Tesla a pris feu.